# Expected value of a multivariate distribution

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, average, random-matrices

Given this random vector:

$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And this probability distribution function that takes it as argument:

$$
f_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
4x_1x_2e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)} & x_1,x_2 \ge 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

How do I calculate expected value of $\mathbf{x}$; that is $E\{\mathbf{x}\}$?

My aim is to calculate the covariance matrix

$$
\mathbf{C_x} = E\left\{(\mathbf{x}-E\{\mathbf{x}\})(\mathbf{x}-E\{\mathbf{x}\})^T\right\}
$$

But I'm stuck at finding mean of $\mathbf{x}$ vector.

Comment: $E[\mathbf{X}]$ is just the vector of means, i.e. the vector containing $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$. Find the densities of $X_1$ and calculate $E[X_1]$ and the same applies to $X_2$.

Comment: You quite properly use a capital letter for the random variable, shown as a suscript on the $f$, and a lower-case letter as the argument to the density function, but above that you're using a lower-case $x$ for the random variable.  The notation is inconsistent.

Comment: @StefanHansen Do I calculate $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$ from marginal densities, or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @hkBattousai: I can't see any other way than obtaining the marginal densities, but maybe others do.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used capital letter in the index because of habit that comes from working with scalar densities. I used small letter in notation below, because they are vectors. I see the inconsistency. Which notation should I stick with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Stefan Hansen in comments, expected values can be found term-by-term.

Notice how your density factors: $\Big(2x_1 e^{-x_1^2}\Big)\Big(2x_2 e^{-x_2^2}\Big)$.  Since it's a function of $x_1$ times a function of $x_2$, the two components of your random vector are independent, so the off-diagonal entries of the matrix will be $0$.  And because of independence, you can find the expected values separately.  And finally, because of symmetry, the two expected values are the same.

Comment: How did you know that you should divide it into factors like $\big(2x_1 e^{-x_1^2}\big)\big(2x_2 e^{-x_2^2}\big)$? There are infinitely many other ways to do it. For example: $\big(4x_1 e^{-x_1^2}\big)\big(x_2 e^{-x_2^2}\big)$, $\big({1 \over 2}x_1 e^{-x_1^2}\big)\big(8x_2 e^{-x_2^2}\big)$, etc...

Comment: @hkBattousai: You want both of them to be densities, i.e. they should integrate to $1$.

Comment: @hkBattousai : If it can be factored as a function of $x_1$ times a function of $x_2$, then the two random variables are independent, regardless of whether the two factors are density functions themselves.  But you can choose the constants in such a way that they are both density functions, and in that case they are the marginal densities.